# What does 'cool toy' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I found a word 'cool toy' in the following sentence in today's New York Times article:
'Spending money on tablet computers may seem an extravagance, but some educators say they are more than just a cool toy.'
What does 'cool toy' mean? What are typical items of cool toy, for instance? Are they electronic toys?

Comment: Always found ironic that english speakers use _cool_ or _hot_ depending on context to mean something fashionable. If you mix, it will give "The coolest toys are selling like hot cakes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cool toy* is not a technical term. Here, *cool* is an informal way of saying *excellent* or *fashionable*; see the definition number 7 at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cool) or [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool). What is cool is highly subjective; different people will have different opinions. For example, some might say that iPhone is cool; others might disagree. A cool toy doesn't have to be electronic. For example, I think that [LEGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego) is extremely cool. (But again, others might disagree and say that [Playmobil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playmobil) is cooler.)

Comment: I think the expression **cool toy** in this context is describing grown-up 'toys', and not so much children toys. An iPhone is a **cool toy**, but LEGO is a cool **toy**.

Comment: @awe: note the word "educators" or just have a look at [the article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/05/education/05tablets.html?_r=1&ref=ipad). It is actually about schools handing out iPads to students. It's talking about kids, sixth graders, and even kindergartners getting their hands on iPads.

Comment: Those Playmobil people are simply wrong. You can ignore them. :)

Comment: Playmobil never felt warm to me, but I would never have called them _cool_ :-)

Answer (score 5):

In this context, *toy* is defined New Oxford American Dictionary as follows:

> an object, esp. a gadget or machine, regarded as providing amusement for an adult

So, yes, an iPad, or similar fancy electronic gadget, could be considered a "cool toy". Other examples of *toys* are luxury cars or motorcycles.

Comment: I now understand 'cool toy' is a fancy, fashionable gadget providing amusement. I didn't imagine that the word 'toys' is applicable to an item like luxuary cars and motorcycles.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Before gadgets became cool, "toy" was used to describe the expensive machines purchased by the rich. For example: `"Check out that sleek Bugatti! That's one of our boss's new toys."`, `"With this new toy," he said, stroking the hull of his yacht, "I've just joined the big boys' club."`

Comment: @Yoichi, @Jimi - also, the word "toy" is used ironically, as in Jimi's examples of a Bugatti and a yacht. These are items that are thousands or hundreds of thousands times more expensive that a child's rubber ball, yet have the same importance (or lack thereof) to someone fabulously wealthy.

Answer (score 3):

*Cool* here is used informally to mean *fashionable*. When the article says it is *more than a cool toy*, it means the toy is not just fashionable but has real value.

Comment: It may also mean it is not just a toy.

Answer (score 2):

`cool toy` means a gadget that you just MUST have because it is is the latest 'thing', but you really don't need it.

In this context where it says `more than just a cool toy`,  it means that it has a practical purpose that you can use for more meaningful tasks (not just to play with...).

Answer (score 1):

A few month ago I said 'awesome gadget' than I walked around considering whether or not I should buy an iPad. It's a `cool toy` nobody really needs it, but my wife.

Comment: This is not intended to be an advertisment just to illustrate: http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/